# how to enable memory profiler only when testing in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, decorator, memory-profiling

I am using `memory_profiler` in python and profiling some piece of code. But I only want that to enable when testing is happening, like the function is being invoked from a test-suite. I don't want the profiler being enabled when code is running in production. Is there any way to do that?

I am open to generic suggestion like "how to enable decorators only when the testing is happening?".

Example code -

```
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile(precision=4)
def my_func():
    a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
    del b
    return a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decorator,

```
@profile(precision=4)
def my_func():
    ...
```

Is just a fancy way of writing this:

```
def my_func():
    ...

my_func = profile(precision=4)(my_func)
```

Therefore if you need a “conditional decorator”, you can apply the condition to the latter:

```
from memory_profiler import profile

testing = False
def my_func():
    a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
    del b
    return a

if testing:
    my_func = profile(precision=4)(my_func)
```

Comment: The variable `my_func` is same as the function name `my_func` was it intentional or just a name?

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' It's intentional

Comment: So you mean if I don't keep the variable name same as function it will not work?

Comment: Yes, as I said in the answer, a decorator used like that, is exactly the same as the latter way. But if you change the latter, they're not the same anymore.

Comment: But what if you want to test multiple methods of different classes that work together? In that case you cant separate it that nicely. What would be your advice in such a case?

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' An alternate approach (possibly better) is to create your own definition of the decorator, set your conditions there, if true, pass along everything to the actual decorator and return it, and if false, just return the original function.